# EHCache RMI Replication on JBoss/EC2 throws java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table

Tags: jboss, replication, rmi, ehcache

Trying to create an EHCache RMI-based cache replication between 2 JBoss 4.2 servers on Amazon EC2. Currently, this is set up as manual peer discovery with one-way replication from Server2 to Server1.

Configuration as under:

Server 1

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
   class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
   properties="peerDiscovery=manual"/>

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
   class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
   properties="hostName=host1, port=40001,  
                     socketTimeoutMillis=3000"/>

<cache name="cache1"
        maxElementsInMemory="0"
        eternal="false"
        overflowToDisk="true"
        timeToIdleSeconds="600"
        timeToLiveSeconds="600"
        diskPersistent="true"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="60"
        statistics="true">
        <cacheEventListenerFactory
                          class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
                          properties="replicatePuts=false, replicateUpdates=false, 
                replicateRemovals=false"/>
</cache>
```

Server 2

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
   class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
   properties="peerDiscovery=manual,
             rmiUrls=//host1:40001/cache1"/>

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
   class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
   properties="hostName=host2, port=40002,  
                     socketTimeoutMillis=3000"/>

<cache name="cache1"
        maxElementsInMemory="0"
        eternal="false"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="7200"
        timeToLiveSeconds="7200">
        <cacheEventListenerFactory
                          class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
                          properties="replicateAsynchronously=false"/>
    </cache>
```

However, when I put new elements into the cache on Server2, it throws the following exception:

```
Jul 10, 2012 3:25:37 PM net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMISynchronousCacheReplicator replicatePutNotification
SEVERE: Exception on replication of putNotification. no such object in table. Continuing...
java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
          at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
          at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
          at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
          at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICachePeer_Stub.put(Unknown Source)
          at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMISynchronousCacheReplicator.replicatePutNotification(RMISynchronousCacheReplicator.java:149)
          at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMISynchronousCacheReplicator.notifyElementPut(RMISynchronousCacheReplicator.java:132)
          at net.sf.ehcache.event.RegisteredEventListeners.notifyListener(RegisteredEventListeners.java:294)
          at net.sf.ehcache.event.RegisteredEventListeners.invokeListener(RegisteredEventListeners.java:284)
          at net.sf.ehcache.event.RegisteredEventListeners.internalNotifyElementPut(RegisteredEventListeners.java:144)
          at net.sf.ehcache.event.RegisteredEventListeners.notifyElementPut(RegisteredEventListeners.java:122)
          at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.notifyPutInternalListeners(Cache.java:1515)
          at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.putInternal(Cache.java:1490)
          at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1417)
          at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1382)
```

I've also tried this with Server2 as a stand-alone Java program (using the same ehcache.xml as shown above) instead of a JBoss server. But as long as Server1 is a JBoss server, I see this exception.

It works great if I deploy Server1 and Server2 (JBoss or Java program) on the same host. But as soon as I move them to different hosts, it dies on me.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

`java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException` means that the object referenced by the stub is not currently exported. It must have been exported at some time, otherwise there would be no stub. Probably it has been garbage-collected, first DGC then local GC. You can guard against that by keep a reference to the remote object (nb not the stub) in a static variable. But it seems like the remote object concerned isn't one of yours but one of theirs, in which case you need to find their bug reporting system.